# deploy error - ServletWrapper failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, weblogic

I'm deploying an application and during the start process I got the message below:

```
<Warning> <HTTP> <brvix5valeas213> <ocr_dev_ms01> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue:     'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1404137636050> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener play.server.ServletWrapper failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1912)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1519)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart(JPAPlugin.java:267)
at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:525)
at play.Play.start(Play.java:526)
at play.Play.init(Play.java:300)
at play.server.ServletWrapper.contextInitialized(ServletWrapper.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:140)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

I tried a lot of suggestions around the Google and I had no success. Furthering information:

- WL 10.3.5
- Windows 2008 R2 64 bits
- JDK 7u9
- Console and Node Manager as Windows Service
- The application needs JPA2. Included "D:\app\oracle\wls1035\modules\javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar" on classpath.
- Both dev and prod environments don't work.
- The application uses your own libs, defined on weblogic.xml, under prefer-web-inf-classes=true
- All hibernate files are included on application lib folder

Comment: Did you try calling `OneToMany.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` as mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376804/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-onetomany-orphanremoval It is almost definitely a classpath issue. You have 2 jar files of different versions on the classpath

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one dependency on the classpath that defines "OneToMany." Something is using an older version of javax.persistence. Just add this line of code before you get the error and see what is printed:

```
System.out.println(javax.persistence.OneToMany.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

The JAR file that is printed is likely the culprit. You need to remove it or update it to use javax.persistence-2.X.X.