# Issue with Hibernate and Spring Injection of autowired dependencies

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autowired

I've just started using hibernate and spring and faced following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.omid.hd.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToOne.orphanRemoval()Z
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.omid.hd.Main.main(Main.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Following are my Entity classes:

```
package com.omid.hd.model;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "SHAPE")
public class Shape {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "ID")
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="SH_TN", referencedColumnName = "TID")private ThumbNail angle;
 public int getId() {
    return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }


 public ThumbNail getAngle() {
    return angle;
 }

 public void setAngle(ThumbNail angle) {
    this.angle = angle;
 }
}

///////////////

@Entity
@Table(name= "thumbnail")
public class ThumbNail {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "TID")
private int id;
}
```

this is my Spring config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.omid.hd.dao.impl" />
    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.omid.hd.service.impl" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
       <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
             <prop 
             key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
             <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>-->
          </props>
       </property>
       <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.omid.hd.model" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and finally my test class:

```
  public class Main 
    {
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");


        }
    }
```

my pom.xml also:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <groupId>com.omid.hd</groupId>
  <artifactId>com-omid-hd</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>com-omid-hd</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I appreciate your help in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591684/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-onetomany-orphanremovalz

Answer (score 3):

Your pom declares that you use the version 1.0 of the JPA spec. But `orphanRemoval` is a field of `OneToOne` that only exists since version 2.0 of the JPA spec.

Hibernate 4.1.9 implements JPA 2.0, so that's what you should declare as dependency.

Comment: I have changed the Jpa version as you said and seems the problem is solved now. TU