# org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'configurationClass' of bean class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, spring-orm

I am trying to migrate to newer hibernate version

in configuration I have replaced

### 1

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

with

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

### 2

```
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate-test.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

with

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate-test.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="configurationClass">
                <value>org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

As a result I see the following error message when I starts the application:

```
    Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'configurationClass' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'configurationClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

P.S.

hibernate dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What hibernate version you are migrating to?

Comment: @Rohit added info in topic

Comment: Hibernte 4 does not have the `configurationClass` property. Remove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
</property>
```

Remove above declaration and try once.

Comment: Now I see new error.  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource ....Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()

Comment: @gstackoverflow I think some lib issues are there please ref this link i think it will solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591684/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-onetomany-orphanremovalz